# WPF MVVM with EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

Database is not creating while running my WPF application. What's wrong with my code:

[image]

App.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="JanathaPOSConn"
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=JanathaDb;Trusted_Connection=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

POCO class 1 :

```
namespace JanathaPOS.Model
{
    [Table("UserRoles")]
    public class UserRole
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

POCO class 2 :

```
namespace JanathaPOS.Model
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context class :

```
namespace JanathaPOS.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    class JanathaPosDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private static JanathaPosDbContext _context;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static JanathaPosDbContext GetContext()
        {
            if (_context == null)
            {
                _context = new JanathaPosDbContext();
            }
            return _context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public JanathaPosDbContext() : base("JanathaPOSConn") { }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

XAML :

```
namespace JanathaPOS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<JanathaPosDbContext>());

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception? What is it? You probably don't want to have a single context for the life of your application, either.

Comment: Getting no error, no exception but database is not get created.

Comment: Sorry! I'm a beginner in WPF. Could you please explain bit more?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with WPF. EF is completely orthogonal. Things to try: 1) Create your context and model in its own project. 2) Create a very simple console application that only instantiates the context, and maybe adds a single new entity or performs a query. I think (but I'm not sure) that the database isn't actually created until the first query or insert. Simplify the problem and it'll be easier to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the context instantiated here. You have to create the context and try to access the data **or** force the initialization:

```
using ( var ctx = new JanathaPosDbContext() )
{
    // access the data 
    var roles = ctx.UserRoles.ToList();         

    // or force the initialization
    ctx.Database.Initialize( true );
}
```